# How do I install El Capitan and ParrotSec dual-boot? (without Kernel Panics)

Tags: macos, partition, startup, kernel-panic

ParrotSec was installed on this machine and it was running fine - meanwhile I could not reach it from Grub2 because if I chose MacOSX-32bit/MacOSX-64bit it popped back a Kernel Panic.

On the other hand MacOSX was on the machine - and it can be reached from:

> Option key - Choosing HDD as boot from Apple boot menu  /// And it was run smoothly

This is why I reinstalled OSX and now Parrot is become unreachable. The Grub options to run Parrot is not showing, only MacOSX.

```
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *160.0 GB   disk0



 1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1



  2:          Apple_CoreStorage Seth                    79.3 GB    disk0s2

  3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3



 4:                 Linux Swap                         25.0 GB    disk0s4



 5:           Linux Filesystem                         54.8 GB    disk0s5
```

- If I start ParrotSec-boot with AdvancedOptions/RescueMode/ReinstallGrubBootloader, it will exit with "unable to install Grub" both onto EFI and Disk5.

  So make this clear ParrotSec and OSX are on the computer but I could not reach ParrotSec because OSX bootloader probably overrode Grub. How can I get back both ParrotSec and MacOSX?